# How to obtain and save the bash "jobspec" for a backgrounded command?

Tags: bash, job-control

When I start a command in the background via `command &`, the process ID of the command can be retrieved from the variable `$!`.  This value can be saved and used in later commands, such as `kill`.

However, a few built-ins, notably `fg` require a "jobspec", which is a special shell thing that starts with `%`.  So if I start a background command, I can foreground it afterward via `command & fg %+`, because `%+` is the jobspec of the most recently backgrounded command.

If I start two commands in the background, I can foreground the first one using `%-`, which is the jobspec that is the previous value of `%+`:  `command1 & command2 & fg %-`.

But this cannot be generalized to three commands.  What is needed in general is to be able to save a `%nnn` jobspec for the command that was just stared in the background.  This can be done by something like `jobs | sed -e '$!d' -e 's/^\[\([0-9]\+].*$/%\1/`, but there ought to be a better way than that.

Comment: Given that job control like `fg` is by default turned off in scripts, it might be that you won't find a simpler answer than just running `jobs` and picking the one you want manually

Comment: Did you know you can use `%string?` as a jobspec?  Where "string" is a unique string in the command, followed by a `?`.  See `man bash`